# Intercepting the Nokia Ctrl/Chr key press in Java

Tags: java-me, keyboard, nokia, qwerty

I'm trying to intercept the Ctrl/Chr key on a full QWERTY Nokia device (E71). It seems like the keyPress event isn't generated for this particular key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance that this key is only a keycode modifier.

You can probably only see whether it is pressed at the same time as another one.

It would not exactly but the first key to not trigger a Canvas.keyPressed() callback on a phone.